# what is $$ in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

there is a script I evolved with it, it has line of command like below :

```
mytemp=`echo ${sourcedir}|awk -F/ '{printf "/%s/tmp",$2}'`/`basename $0`-$1.$$
```

at the last of the command we see `$$` that produces a number. when I use `echo $$` in bash I also see a number like bellow:

```
 #echo $$
 23019
```

what exactly is this number, and what is `$$`?

Comment: It's your current shell pid

Comment: That question is not completely right about the answer.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide:](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)

> $$ is the process ID (PID) of the script itself.
>
> $BASHPID is the process ID of the current instance of Bash. This is not the same as the $$ variable, but it often gives the same
>   result.

Answer (score 18):

`$$` is the process ID of the current shell instance. So in your case the number, 23019, is the PID of that instance of `bash`.

The following should give you a better idea:

```
ps -p $$
```

Comment: It often finds use in scripts to construct "unique" temp file names.

Comment: @chaos Those scripts should use `mktemp`.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda. `tmp_file=\`mktemp /tmp/my_file_XXX\` ; trap 'rm -f $tmp_file' EXIT` is indeed safer (making sure $tmp_file is deleted at shell exit)

Comment: @NoamManos: even better if `mktemp` is used without the `/tmp/my_file_XXX` argument, and let the system choose an appropriate path (which might not even be in `/tmp`)