# How to list the open file descriptors (and the files they refer to) in my current bash session

Tags: linux, bash, file-descriptors, open-files

I am running in an interactive bash session. I have created some file descriptors, using exec, and I would like to list what is the current status of my bash session.

Is there a way to list the currently open file descriptors?

Comment: check this [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66235/how-to-display-open-file-descriptors-but-not-using-lsof-command)

Comment: @Kamaraj thanks. So bash has no built-in to do that? I need to use linux-specific features?

Comment: `bash` is not part of the kernel, so it can not know what other processes are doing, even those that it started.

Comment: @JuliePelletier: but child processes do not change the file descriptors of the parent process, do they?

Comment: hi, what do you mean by "I have created some file descriptors, using exec"?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Yes, this will list all open file descriptors:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Dec 28 00:56 0 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Dec 28 00:56 1 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Dec 28 00:56 2 -> /dev/pts/6
lrwx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Dec 28 00:56 255 -> /dev/pts/6
l-wx------ 1 isaac isaac 64 Dec 28 00:56 4 -> /home/isaac/testfile.txt
```

Of course, as usual: 0 is stdin, 1 is stdout and 2 is stderr.
The 4th is an open file (to write) in this case.

Comment: what is /proc/$$ ? specifically how does "$$" work?

Comment: @JZ.`$$` will give the process ID of the currently running shell. Try `echo $$` and `ps` and compare their outputs. Similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291570/what-is-in-bash).

Answer (score 15):

```
lsof -a -p $$
```

Network fd only:

```
lsof -i -a -p $$
```

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you want to list the file descriptors that are attached to any terminal, you can use `lsof`/`fuser` or similar like:

```
$ lsof -p $$ 2>/dev/null | awk '$NF ~ /\/pts\//'
bash    32406 foobar    0u   CHR 136,31      0t0      34 /dev/pts/31
bash    32406 foobar    1u   CHR 136,31      0t0      34 /dev/pts/31
bash    32406 foobar    2u   CHR 136,31      0t0      34 /dev/pts/31
bash    32406 foobar    3u   CHR 136,31      0t0      34 /dev/pts/31
bash    32406 foobar  255u   CHR 136,31      0t0      34 /dev/pts/31
```

These tools basically parse `/proc`, so you can just access `/proc/$$/fd/` too e.g.:

```
ls /proc/$$/fd/*
```

Comment: The selection of `\/pts\/` rejects open files like `exec 4>testfile.txt`

Comment: @sorontar Yep, like i said this one is only for listing the ones attached to any terminal.

Comment: `ls /proc/$$/fd/*` doesn't work for me. I get `ls: /proc/48855/fd: No such file or directory` :(

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`lsof`](https://github.com/lsof-org/lsof) utility to print all file descriptors for the current shell process (process identified by `-p $$`) *and* (`-a`) where the file descriptor is numeric (`-d 0-256`):

```
$ lsof -p $$ -a -d 0-256
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bash    16883  ant    0u   CHR 136,15      0t0   18 /dev/pts/15
bash    16883  ant    1u   CHR 136,15      0t0   18 /dev/pts/15
bash    16883  ant    2u   CHR 136,15      0t0   18 /dev/pts/15
bash    16883  ant  255u   CHR 136,15      0t0   18 /dev/pts/15
```

Pipe into Awk to print only the file descriptor and its corresponding filename:

```
$ lsof -p $$ -a -d 0-256  | awk '{ printf("%4s:\t%s\n", $4, $NF) }'
  FD:   NAME
  0u:   /dev/pts/15
  1u:   /dev/pts/15
  2u:   /dev/pts/15
255u:   /dev/pts/15
```

Note: when `lsof` prints the file descriptors, it appends the following code to indicate the file access mode:

- `r` – read access
- `w` – write access
- `u` – read and write access

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to want a graphical solution, `gnome-system-monitor` allows you to see the opened file descriptors of a process. Right click on any process opens a contextual menu, then you can click `Open Files`. Or you can just select the process and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Bonus: There is also an option in the sandwich menu to search opened files by filename

[image: Screenshot of System Monitor]