# Search for running script PID by script name

Tags: shell-script, ps

I have the following script

```
hello.sh
--------
while :
do
    echo "hello"
    sleep 20
done
```

And when I ran the above script, I got 2627 as the PID of the script

```
root@localhost ~]# ./hello.sh &
[1] 2627
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Now when I'm running the ps command in another terminal, I'm not getting the script name in the output

```
[root@localhost ~]# ps -ef| grep 262[7]
root      2627  1582  0 19:19 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
root      3427  2627  0 19:52 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 20
[root@localhost ~]#
```

$$ is the PID of the main shell where I'm running the script. I know that inside the script I can put $$ to get the PID of the script, but that's not my intention here.

Once I ran the long running script in the background and suppose I have closed the terminal accidentally, then is there a way to grep the PID using the script name or any other means?

FYI

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo $$
2586
[root@localhost ~]# ps -ef| grep 262[7]
root      2627  1582  0 19:19 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
root      3657  2627  0 20:02 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 20
[root@localhost ~]# ps -ef| grep bas[h]
root      1517  1513  0 18:43 pts/18   00:00:00 -bash
root      1582  1578  0 18:45 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
root      2586  2581  0 19:18 pts/54   00:00:00 -bash
root      2627  1582  0 19:19 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
[root@localhost ~]#
```

2586 is the PID of the main shell and inside it, I have run the hello.sh script. It created a new shell and started running the commands inside it. All these basic I know. This is not a duplicate question. Please see the output to understand it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is $$ in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291570/what-is-in-bash)

Comment: consult the duplicate, it's basicaly `$$`

Comment: Do you want the PID ? or do you want the command running ?

Comment: What if someone else ran a "./hello.sh", or if you ran a second one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a proper she-bang line (`#! /bin/sh` or `#! /bin/bash`) to your script if you want it to appear with its name in the process list.

Example:

```
$ cat foo
sleep 10

$ ./foo &
[4] 4403
$ ps -q 4403
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4403 pts/3    00:00:00 bash

$ cat bar
#! /bin/sh
sleep 10

$ ./bar &
[5] 4406
$ ps -q 4406
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4406 pts/3    00:00:00 bar
```

Otherwise, on linux you can still find the name of the script from the `/proc/PID/fd` directory:

```
$ ./foo &
[2] 5125
$ ls -l /proc/5125/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 ahq ahq 64 Oct 22 17:57 0 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 ahq ahq 64 Oct 22 17:57 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 ahq ahq 64 Oct 22 17:57 2 -> /dev/pts/3
lr-x------ 1 ahq ahq 64 Oct 22 17:57 254 -> /tmp/foo
lrwx------ 1 ahq ahq 64 Oct 22 17:57 255 -> /dev/pts/3
```

Notice to forth line, the `254` fd which points to the path of the script being run. With other shells than `bash` it will be other `fd`, like `3` or `10`.

That could also be reverse searched with `lsof /tmp/foo`.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I got another question now. when I killed the 2627 PID and then I grepped for it, I got the below and it showed me the path of the script as well. If I run the script with the absolute path I will get it in ps output and if I run with the relative path i.e ./ in this case 
[root@localhost ~]# kill -9 2627
[root@localhost ~]# ps -ef| grep 262[7]
[1]+  Killed                  ./hello.sh  (wd: /tmp/test/scripts/hello.sh)
(wd now: ~)

Comment: The ps output could show either the "process name" (the first 15 characters of the basename of the executable) or the full command line, as it was passed to `execve`. `ps -ef` will show the latter. `ps -eo pid,comm,args` will show both. There is no difference if it was run via an absolute or  relative path, or a simple command looked up in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you could:

```
grep -l hello.sh /proc/*/task/*/comm 2>/dev/null
```

... which would report back any of your processes with "hello.sh" in their command-line (pid 26560, when I ran it):

> /proc/26560/task/26560/comm

The stderr redirection is to drop grep's complaint about your current process' comm file (/proc/self/task/$$/comm) disappearing between the time the shell expands the wildcarded path and when grep decides to open it for reading/grepping.

If you run a second "hello.sh", you'll get two results back, etc:

```
$ ./hello.sh &
[2] 28328
$ grep -l hello.sh /proc/*/task/*/comm 2>/dev/null
/proc/26560/task/26560/comm
/proc/28328/task/28328/comm
```

Comment: I'm getting nothing when I ran your command and I'm running this on CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708