# What does echo $$ do?

Tags: variable, echo, variable-substitution

I was messing around with `echo` and was trying stuff like `echo ~`. When I was trying to use `$` to substitute environment variables I accidentally tried `echo $$`. Surprisingly instead of an empty line I get a six-digit number, `269523`. I kept trying the same command and the number did not change. However when I tried it a few hours later the number changed but it was still a six-digit number. What is the meaning of `echo $$`? Are there any other chars like `$` that have special meaning in the context of environment variables?

Comment: I believe it gives you the process ID of the current process:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/what-does-mean-in-the-shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78493/what-does-mean-in-the-shell)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is $$ in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291570/what-is-in-bash)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which are the (Bash) shell special parameters/variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218270/which-are-the-bash-shell-special-parameters-variables)

Answer (score 0):

It's simply the `pid` of the current `shell`:

```
$ tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$$/cmdline
bash
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$` parameter (whose value you are outputting with `echo` by prefixing it with another `$`) is a special parameter (not an environment variable) in all POSIX and POSIX-like shells (like `bash` and `zsh` and others).  It holds the process ID (PID) of the current shell.

This parameter is defined in the POSIX standard (see [Special Parameters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02)) as

> `$`
> Expands to the decimal process ID of the invoked shell. In a subshell (see [Shell Execution Environment](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_12)), `$` shall expand to the same value as that of the current shell.

Since both `echo "$$"` and `(echo "$$")` output the same PID even though the second command is executed in a subshell, the `bash` shell has introduced the `BASHPID` variable, which is updated in subshells. This is also not an environment variable.

The reference above will also list the eight special parameter that may be the ones you are asking about.  Note that the text below is using my own words and that you should look at the standard or in the manual for the specific shell you're using to get a more specific description.

- `@`: `"$@"` is the list of positional parameters (usually the command line arguments to the current script or function).
- `*`: `"$*"` is a single string with the positional parameters concatenated using the first character of `$IFS` (usually a space) as the delimiter.
- `#`: `"$#"` is the number of positional parameters.
- `?`: `"$?"` is the exit status of the most recently executed command.
- `-`: `"$-"` is a string containing the currently set shell options.
- `$`: `"$$"` is described above (the PID of the current shell).
- `!`: `"$!"` is the PID of the most recently started asynchronous job ("background process").
- `0`: `"$0"` is the name of the current shell or shell script. This is used in diagnostic messages.

Answer (score 0):

In Bourne-like and csh-like shells (and `perl`), `$` is a special parameter that expands to the id of the process that executed the shell interpreter. So `$$` is parameter expansion syntax to expand the value of that parameter.

It's not easy to look for in the documentation as `$` is also a special character in the search syntax of `info` and the `less` pager (typically used for paging man pages) at least and `$` occurs everywhere in the manual.

In the `zsh` manual, you'll find it in the *Parameters Set By The Shell* section (`info -n 'Parameters Set By The Shell' zsh`):

> `$` 
> The process ID of this shell.  Note that this indicates the
> original shell started by invoking zsh; all processes forked from
> the shells without executing a new program, such as subshells
> started by (...), substitute the same value.

In the bash manual, in the *Special Parameters* section:

> `'$'`
> (`$$`) Expands to the process ID of the shell.  In a '()' subshell,
> it expands to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the
> subshell.

Both zsh and bash manuals have an index entry for those (and most special variables and parameters) though, so you can get to it with:

```
info zsh '$'
info bash '$'
```

As both note, it's not necessarily the pid of the shell process interpreting (or executing since `echo` is builtin) that `echo $$` command. For that, see the `BASHPID` special variable in bash and `$sysparam[pid]` in zsh.

Beware that in Bourne-like shells other than zsh, you'd need:

```
echo "$$"
```

as `echo $$` without the quotes there is special syntax to invoke a split+glob operator which you don't need here. In practice though, you'll only see the difference if `$IFS` contains digits.

```
bash-5.0$ echo $$ "$$"
33664 33664
bash-5.0$ IFS=6
bash-5.0$ echo $$ "$$"
33  4 33664
```